# How to make VSCode Emmet auto-import on tab expansion a React component

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, emmet

The problem is that depending on the way I auto-complete a React component name while typing it, Visual Studio Code does or does not import the component at the top of the file. There are two ways:

1. Type in the opening bracket ("<"), begin typing in the component name, accept the VSCode *suggestion to import it*, then type the rest of the name with its  closing bracket, and then let VS Code auto closing tag feature do the rest. The output will allways be like `<Component></Component>`
2. Start typing the component name directly (with no "<"), *emmet suggestion will show up*, and then you can optionally type "/" at the end of the name (to make it self-closing tag) then tab and the emmet expansion happens. Output can be `<Component></Component>` or `<Component />`

With option 2 **I won't get the import added to the top of the file like with option 1**. But it is way more powerful and productive as I can use emmet features like adding ids, classNames, arbitrary properties, nest components inside it and setting inner text all in one go, example:

```
CustomPanel.std-pnl>CustomImage[someProp={someValue}]/+CustomButton#btn-1.std-btn[onClick={onClickHandler}]{This the button text}
```

If I emmet expand that it results in:

```
<CustomPanel className="std-pnl">
  <CustomImage someProp={someValue} />
  <CustomButton id="btn-1" className="std-btn" onClick={onClickHandler}>This the button text</CustomButton>
</CustomPanel>
```

**Is there a way (settings or something) to tell emmet expansion to import the component names being expanded?** Just like the normal IntelliSense suggestion does it.

---

My current config of these tools:
VS Code version 1.77.3

Emmet enabled in vscode settings.json:

```
"emmet" { 
  "includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "typescript": "typescriptreact"
  },
  "showExpandedAbbreviation": "always", // this is the default, no need to add it explicitly
}
```

I have also tried changing this in settings.json (but no difference):

```
"js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true,
```

Comment: auto import is not an emmet feature it is a refactor/quick fix feature

Answer (score 1):

No, Emmet doesn’t support such feature, since it’s just a generic way to convert small abbreviation into a full code fragment.

But is sounds like an interesting feature, will think about how to support it